# Grouping by Time ranges in Linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I've been getting stuck into some linq queries for the first time today and I'm struggling with some of the more complicated ones.  I'm building a query to extract data from a table to build a graph.  The tables colums I'm interested in are **Id**, **Time** and **Value**.

The user will select a start time, an end time and the number of intervals (points) to graph.  The value column will averaged for each interval.

I can do this with a linq request for each interval but I'm trying to write it in one query so I only need to go to the database once.

So far I have got:

```
var timeSpan = endTime.Subtract(startTime);
var intervalInSeconds = timeSpan.TotalSeconds / intervals;

var wattList = (from t in _table
                where t.Id == id
                    && t.Time >= startTime
                    && t.Time <= endTime
                group t by  intervalInSeconds // This is the bit I'm struggling with
                    into g
                    orderby g.Key 
                    select g.Average(a => a.Value))
                ).ToList();
```

Any help on grouping over time ranges will be most welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this myself for exactly the same situation you describe.

For speed, modified the database's datapoints table to include an integer-based time column, `SecondsSince2000`, and then worked with that value in my LINQ to SQL query. `SecondsSince2000` is a computed column defined as:

```
datediff(second, dateadd(month,1200,0), DataPointTimeColumn) PERSISTED
```

Where `DataPointTimeColumn` is the name of the column that stores the datapoint's time. The magic function call `dateadd(month,1200,0)` returns 2000-01-01 at midnight, so the column stores the number of seconds since that time.

The LINQ to SQL query is then made much simpler, and faster:

```
int timeSlotInSeconds = 60;

var wattList = 
    (from t in _table
     where t.Id == id
           && t.Time >= startTime
           && t.Time <= endTime
     group t by t.SecondsSince2000 - (t.SecondsSince2000 % timeSlotInSeconds)
     into g
     orderby g.Key 
     select g.Average(a => a.Value))).ToList();
```

If you can't modify your database, you can still do this:

```
var baseTime = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1);

var wattList = 
    (from t in _table
     where t.Id == id
           && t.Time >= startTime
           && t.Time <= endTime
     let secondsSince2000 = (int)(t.Time- baseTime).TotalSeconds
     group t by secondsSince2000 - (secondsSince2000 % timeSlotInSeconds)
     into g
     orderby g.Key 
     select g.Average(a => a.Value))).ToList();
```

The query will be quite a bit slower.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example I wrote a while ago. It sounds like what you are trying to do, but I'm not sure if it does the grouping in SQL or by .NET.

http://mikeinmadison.wordpress.com/2008/03/12/datetimeround/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do something like:

```
var wattList = (from t in _table
                where t.Id == id
                   && t.Time >= startTime
                   && t.Time <= endTime
               ).GroupBy(x => (int) ((x.Time - startTime).TotalSeconds / intervalInSeconds))
                .Select(grp => grp.Average(x => x.Value));
```